# how to display previous answer for single-answer questions in quiz

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

In my **[Angular quiz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app)**, I'm adding a "previous answers" feature and I'm having some difficulty with displaying the previous answers for ***single-answer*** questions.

Here below are the 1) TypeScript function in my *QuizService*, 2) the snippet for multiple-answer questions that displays the previous answers, and 3) my attempt at the *single-answer* questions template that I need help with.

The *single-answer* questions should show one corresponding previous answer per question.

Please could you help to resolve this issue. Thank you!

*QuizService* code:

```
setPreviousUserAnswersText(questions: QuizQuestion[], previousAnswers): void {
  for (let i = 0; i < previousAnswers.length; i++) {
    if (previousAnswers[i].length === 1) {
      const previousAnswersSingleText = questions[i].options[previousAnswers[i] - 1].text;
      this.previousAnswers.push(previousAnswersSingleText);
    }
    if (previousAnswers[i].length > 1) {
      const previousAnswerMultiple = previousAnswers[i].slice();
      for (let j = 0; j < previousAnswerMultiple.length; j++) {
        const previousAnswersMultipleText = questions[i].options[previousAnswerMultiple[j] - 1].text;          
        this.previousAnswersMultipleTextArray.push(previousAnswersMultipleText);
      }
      this.previousAnswers.push(this.previousAnswersMultipleTextArray);
    }
  }
}
```

*Multiple-Answer* HTML template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="option.selected">
  ...
  <div *ngFor="let previousAnswer of previousAnswers; index as j" class="previous-answer-text">
    <span *ngIf="previousAnswers[j].length > 1">
        {{ previousAnswer | join }} were selected in your previous quiz.
    </span>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

*Single-Answer* HTML template (need help with this):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="option.selected">
  ...  
  <!-- TODO: get this working -->
  <div *ngFor="let previousAnswer of previousAnswers; index as j" class="previous-answer-text">
    <span *ngIf="previousAnswers[j].length === 1">
      &ldquo;{{ previousAnswer }}&rdquo; was selected in your previous quiz.
    </span>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: hi! does multi answer questions work? tried looking at the link you included and couldn't move past the first question. Also, can you please explain a bit more what's not working for you (at least until the link works)?

Comment: That's weird, it works fine for me. Can you try now? I'm trying to get the previous user answers to display in the next quiz if the user repeats the quiz. The answers to the multi-answer question show in the next quiz but not the single-answer.